# Update PHP file constant from C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, file-manipulation

I need to update a constant defined in a PHP file. The `constants.php` file is quite simple:

```
<?php
$firstConstant = "abcd";
$third = "abcd";

$updatedOn = "23 April 2001";
?>
```

Now what I need is for my C# application to update the `$updatedOn` constant in this file to the present date.

How can I accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: regular expression + replace? Why don't you use a config file?

Comment: That is what I need help with... I haven't used regular expressions before... And how do I use a config file? This file is used by other PHP pages to extract the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a regular expression which matches `$updatedOn = "23 April 2001";`, generate the replacement line to go in the file and then use the `String.Replace` method to replace your entire line with the new one you have created. Here's a regex to get you started:

`\$updatedOn = \"([A-Za-z\W0-9]+)\"`

For something a bit more flexible, you could write a [simple parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) which understands a subset of PHP - i.e. code tags and assignments/string constants - parse the file, put the key/value pairs into a dictionary, update the relevant values, and write it back out again.

Some Regular Expression resources:

- [30 minute regex tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx)
- [Regex in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [An example of using sub groups](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Regular-Expressions/WorkingwithSubgroups.htm)

Comment: OMG! Write a parser! If this doesn't get me a raise, nothing else will! "Well, you see, I wrote a custom, dynamic parser that understands a _whole_ subset of PHP, including code tags and assignments/string constants, to make this work" ;) Thanks!

Comment: It's a great way to waste a few weekends :)